# Remove domain from deleted project

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I added and vaerified a custom domain in a project, so after some tests, I deleted that project and created a new one.

When I try to add a custom domain, I get an error saying tha specied domain is mapped to another project.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you deleted it within 30-days, it's probable that your project is "being deleted" (but is not entirely deleted) .

If so, you have options:

- Wait for it to be entirely deleted (including presumably its Cloud DNS records).
- Restore it and delete the Cloud DNS records that you wish to recover, redelete it.
- Contact Google Cloud Support and have that team help you.

See:

https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#restoring_a_project

Comment: Restore didn't work, I tried, but domain configs didn't restored. I'll wait it to be deleted completely. Ty.